# RegularExpressionValidator is not working

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation

I'm total **newbie** in using asp.net and I have this regular expression validator that was working perfectly fine before but after I made a huge edit to my textboxes  its not working anymore.

In before edit, when I try to submit the form, if my textbox is empty or the value = "" it will show the error message and will **NOT** redirect to another page.

In after edit, when I try to submit the form, whether the textbox is empty or not it will redirect to another page. **Not stopping the page from redirecting or showing the validator**

before edit.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txttstImmLen" CssClass="forImmLenTb" runat="server" Width="118" Text="Enter Value Here" OnClick="this.value=''" onblur="tryPlaceholder(this,'Enter Value Here')" ></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="vldtstImmLen" ControlToValidate="txttstImmLen" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Immersion Length" Text="*" ValidationExpression="(0*[1-9]\d*)" Runat="server"/>
```

after edit

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txttstImmLen" CssClass="forImmLenTb" runat="server" Width="118" onblur="tryPlaceholder(this);"></asp:TextBox>&nbsp;
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="vldtstImmLen" ControlToValidate="txttstImmLen" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Immersion Length" Text="*" ValidationExpression="(0*[1-9]\d*)" runat="server"/>&nbsp;</td>
```

Please help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`RegularExpressionValidator`s don't check empty values. You need to also use a `RequiredFieldValidator`.

Clarification per @KarlAnderson's comment: You had placeholder text before your edit that caused the `RegularExpressionValidator` to check the value.

Comment: but how can you explain that it shows in the before Edit code?

Comment: And the reason it worked before the edit was because you had an initial `Text` value of `Enter Value Here`, thus the regex had something to process and attempt to match.

Comment: Oh I see... I guess I have no choice but to add a RequiredFieldValidator. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

You may need to set the ValidationGroup property.  If the control that causes validation has it set.

That was my problem.

Comment: The OP does not use a Validation Group.