# RegularExpressionValidator not firing up

Tags: asp.net, regex

I need to validate that one field is activated if a field doesn't contain numbers or a hyphen. A valid string would be 11111111-1.

```
 <asp:textbox runat="server" ID="tbRutDvEmpresaNoAfiliada" CssClass="form-control input-sm" placeholder="12345678-9" autocomplete="off" />
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="rev1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="tbRutDvEmpresaNoAfiliada" 
                ErrorMessage="Enter only numbers and hyphen"  ForeColor="Red" ValidationExpression="^(\d{8}-$)" EnableClientScript="false"
               ></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

It's the first time I use this particular control so I don't know if it needs anything else to work. When I press the submit form button with a wrong string the control does nothing to alert the user and saves the form.

Comment: The pattern `^(\d{8}-$)` will not match `11111111-1`

Comment: Thanks. That should trigger an error anyway but it's not doing so

Comment: What do you mean by "the control does nothing"? Does the form get submitted? What is the expected behavior? Note that `a field doesn't contain numbers or a hyphen` is different from matching `^\d{8}-\d$` but you mean matching the full pattern right?

Comment: the regular expression validator doesn't show any errors. That's what I mean.

Comment: Did you check this page? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18110449/regularexpressionvalidator-is-not-working

Comment: Yes, it doesn't address my issue. This field can be empty.

Comment: Should this be there? `Error="Enter only numbers and hyphen"` I don't see it [listed here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.regularexpressionvalidator?view=netframework-4.8.1).

Comment: I added it later, I'll remove it from the question